# Attach an event to a custom attribute in a <td /> with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQgrid for doing a table and I want to add an event to a concrete column and I don't want to pass html with PHP so I want to attach an event and do some work. The problem is that there is no class and no id, I just have this:

```
<td aria-describedby="list_description" title="lorem ipsum" style="" role="gridcell">lorem ipsum</td>
```

All the `<td />`'s have a aria-describedby, in this case the list_description is where I want to attach an event. In a class way, I'll do something like `$(".list_description").live("click",function(){});` (because is loaded via AJAX) but how I can do it with that custom attribute?

And then, when I click to an `area-describedby="list_description"` I need to get the value of `area-describedby="list_id"` that is in the same `.

An example code:

```
<tr>
    <td aria-describedby="list_id" title="1" style="" role="gridcell">1</td>
    <td aria-describedby="list_description" title="lorem ipsum" style="" role="gridcell">lorem ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td aria-describedby="list_id" title="2" style="" role="gridcell">2</td>
    <td aria-describedby="list_description" title="lorem ipsum" style="" role="gridcell">lorem ipsum</td>
</tr>
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("td[aria-describedby='list_description']").click(function(){
    var prev = $(this).prev().html();
    alert(prev);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/BvLns/1/).

jQuery allows you to search for elements with a given attribute. (`[aria-describedby='list_description']`). More about that selector [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Just in case, you can omit single quotes `$("td[aria-describedby=list_description]").click(...)`